# Swap left/right audio channels, but not for headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Cable length issues forced me to place my stereo speakers (of a 2.1 analog sound system) the other way around on my table, so now I need to swap the stereo channels in Ubuntu.

What I tried so far was changing the line

```
channel-map = left,right
```

to

```
channel-map = right,left
```

in file /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf under the

```
[Mapping analog-stereo]
```

section. This worked for my speakers, but unfortunately it also affects my headphones.